# Definition of \@vobeyspaces

Tags: macros, verbatim, latex-base

In section 53.3 of `source2e`, the macro `\@vobeyspaces` (one internal macro for `verbatim` environment) is defined as

```
{\catcode`\ =\active%
\gdef\@vobeyspaces{\catcode`\ \active\let \@xobeysp}}
```

Is there any reason why `` \catcode`\ =\active `` is used twice here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

The first application of `` \catcode`\ =\active `` means that for the rest of the group, any space tokens are tokenized as active chars not as spaces. That's needed so that

```
\let \@xobeysp
```

will set an active space equal to `\@xobeysp`: notice that the space after `\let` here is *not* dropped as it's catcode-13.

The second `` \catcode`\ \active `` means that spaces tokenized *after* `\@vobeyspaces` is used will be active: that's needed so that it actually does the job.

If we had only the second setting then `\@vobeyspaces` would fail as spaces would still be tokenized as catcode-10. If we had only the first setting then the definition of `\@vobeyspaces` would be defective and `\let` `\@xobeysp` to whatever immediately follows the use of `\@vobeyspaces`.

Comment: Do you mix the first and the second one? When I delete the ``\catcode`\ \active`` in the first line, LaTeX will complain `! Too many }'s`; however, when delete the one in the second line, it only gives wrong result (spaces are not obeyed, but no error).

Comment: My test is `\@vobeyspaces{he ll  o}`.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng Yes, sorry: fixed

Comment: Why does the second `\catcode` have no effect (i.e. change the space's catcode in `\let \@xobeysp` ) when defining `\@vobeyspaces`?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng Category codes are set when tokens are read: that happens when the `\def` occurs, well before the _body_ of the macro is executed.